# How to convert long format to wide format data over multiple variable (Column) and be stacked onto each other?

Tags: r, tidyr, reshape2

I have a monthly time series data (1987-2017) for 20 station. I want to convert the long format data to wide format data such that all the data covering 20 station are in one data frame.

```
head(Monthly_rainfall2[-1:-20,1:5]) #long format data

# A tibble: 6 x 5
  Year  Month  stn1    stn2   stn3
  <chr> <ord> <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>
1 1987  Jan      NA       NA    0  
2 1987  Feb      NA       NA   60.5
3 1987  Mar      NA       NA   66  
4 1987  Apr      NA       NA   64  
5 1987  May      NA       NA  183. 
6 1987  Jun      NA       NA  216
```

Note that the Month Column is a ordered factor.

```
 dput(Monthly_rainfall2[21:50,1:4])
 structure(list(Year = c("1987", "1987", "1987", "1987", "1987", 
"1987", "1987", "1987", "1987", "1987", "1987", "1987", "1988", 
"1988", "1988", "1988", "1988", "1988", "1988", "1988", "1988", 
"1988", "1988", "1988", "1989", "1989", "1989", "1989", "1989", 
"1989"), Month = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", 
"Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
), class = c("ordered", "factor")), stn1 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
), stn2 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -30L))
```

I have tried the following code

```
library(tidyr)

wide_data <- spread(Monthly_rainfall2[1:3], Month, stn1 )
```

The above code provides what I want however, I am not able to produce for all station at once in a single dataframe

I want my data frame to appear like this, where stn2 starts immediately after stn1 and subsequently follows the same pattern for all the station

```
Year     Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
#stn1
1987     0.8 0.5 0.8 2   20   25  30  30  21  22 3    0
1988     1   1.2  1.8 2  20   22   25 21   15  12  10  9
...
2017     0.5  1  14  19   17   14  15  13  10  14  18  10
#stn2
1987     0.8 0.5 0.8 2   20   25  30  30  21  22 3    0
1988     1   1.2  1.8 2  20   22   25 21   15  12  10  9
...
2017     0.5  1  14  19   17   14  15  13  10  14  18  10
#stn3
1987     0.8 0.5 0.8 2   20   25  30  30  21  22 3    0
1988     1   1.2  1.8 2  20   22   25 21   15  12  10  9
...
2017     0.5  1  14  19   17   14  15  13  10  14  18  10
```

Comment: Please use a `dput` of the input example

Comment: It has been added @akrun

Comment: Can you check the solution posted below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution using `data.table`

```
DT <- as.data.table(df)

#filling all ne NAs for optical rasons
DT[, c("stn1", "stn2")  := .(sample(1:100, 30), sample(1:100, 30))]

dcast(DT, Month ~ Year, value.var = c("stn1", "stn2")) %>%
  melt(id.vars = 1, variable.name = "year") %>%
  dcast(year ~ Month, value.var = "value") -> DT2

        year Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
1: stn1_1987  98   5  89  84  75  36   4  34  26  78  33  28
2: stn1_1988  67  74  40  63   9  19  79  61  66  93  47  62
3: stn1_1989  68  29   7  46  54  87  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
4: stn2_1987  31  61  74  89  46  54  70  80  84   6  96  32
5: stn2_1988  75  71  11  99  20   7  77  13  52  14   2  41
6: stn2_1989  83  22  97  43  59  15  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

If you want `year`and `stn`seperated you can do:

```
DT2[, c("stn", "year") := tstrsplit(year, "_", fixed=TRUE)]

   year Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec  stn
1: 1987  98   5  89  84  75  36   4  34  26  78  33  28 stn1
2: 1988  67  74  40  63   9  19  79  61  66  93  47  62 stn1
3: 1989  68  29   7  46  54  87  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA stn1
4: 1987  31  61  74  89  46  54  70  80  84   6  96  32 stn2
5: 1988  75  71  11  99  20   7  77  13  52  14   2  41 stn2
6: 1989  83  22  97  43  59  15  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA stn2
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfectly like what I actually want. I did not know about the dcast() function.

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

We could `gather` into 'long' format and then do a `spread`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
   gather(key, val, Bhur:Chamkhar) %>%
   spread(Month, val)
```

NOTE: The OP's `dput` had only NA for "Bhur/Chamkhar" columns